# PHP header() not redirecting, only posting HTML of redirection page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I made sure that I was not sending any client sided data before hand and I turned on error reporting but nothing is happening.

It's a simple login script with a redirection on validation.

```
    <?php
include_once "database-handler2.php";
require "password.php";

$UserName = $_POST["name"];
$Password = $_POST["pass"];

if(isset($UserName))
{
    $query = "SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username='$UserName'";
    $hashed_password = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($hashed_password))
    {
       $res = $row[0];
    } 


    if(password_verify($Password, $res)) {
       // Show Errors
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors','On');
      // Redirect
      header('Location:http://example.com/ex/index.php', true);
      die('redirect');
    }
}
```

I have made sure that the other included php's don't have an extra whitespace or anything else. Using AJAX the success function does nothing, and if I turn on alert() or debug.log() the success message of the PHP's response (which there shouldn't be one) then I get a print out of the page I'm trying to redirect to's HTML without any error or other information under or above it.

Javascript code:

```
    $('#submitButton').click(function()
{
        var userName = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/handlers/login-handler.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:
        {
            name: userName,
            pass: pass
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
                    alert(msg);
        }               
    });
});
```

Please note that if I take the alert(msg); out than if I click the button nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: The redirect is redirecting where AJAX reads the response from. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: AJAX never reloads the page by itself, that's the whole point. If you want to redirect after an AJAX request, you have to do that in the Javascript code.

Comment: Why are you using AJAX if you want to reload the page from the place where PHP redirects to? Use an ordinary form submission.

Comment: You should redirect your page onSuccess using javascript; not by php because its an ajax request.

Comment: @everyone thank you for the comments however when I try to redirect with Javascript my sessions are lost. How would I go about redirecting with the header via php without submitting a form?

Comment: @Brandon If you are storing information in php sessions, then they won't go if you redirect with JS.

Answer (score 1):

remove this line of your php code

`header('Location:http://example.com/ex/index.php', true);`

and add below line of code on the success response of your ajax.

`window.location.href="http://example.com/ex/index.php"`

If you are AJAX then server side redirection will not work, you have to redirect with jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should return `success` type response from your php code to ajax response and then you should use `window.location` JS code to get your page redirected after successful process.

Comment: @Brandon If you are storing information in php sessions, then they won't go if you redirect with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use javascript/jQuery to submit the form, but use a standard html form instead. You don't need any javascript to submit a form.

```html
<form method="post" action="/handlers/login-handler.php">
    <label for="user">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```